# How do microservices make it easier to avoid overly-tight coupling between components?

Tags: architecture, rest, libraries, enterprise-architecture, microservices

I read [in this article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) about microservice architecture by M. Fowler:

> Another consequence of using services as components is a more explicit
>   component interface. Most languages do not have a good mechanism for
>   defining an explicit Published Interface. Often it's only
>   documentation and discipline that prevents clients breaking a
>   component's encapsulation, leading to overly-tight coupling between
>   components. Services make it easier to avoid this by using explicit
>   remote call mechanisms.

I'm not even sure how to ask. How are microservices better than libraries in enforcing an interface contract? How is a REST endpoint better than a Java function? Can somebody elaborate, maybe give an example?

Comment: "Published Interface" is his own made up term. click on the hyperlink https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PublishedInterface.html

Comment: @Ewan Thanks, I had read that article, and I understand that concept, but still it doesn't help me to understand the reasons behind this text.

Comment: I think hes just saying, that the micro service is going to be in a separate code base and thus harder to change than a library in the same codebase, which you can refactor easily. If you get your library from a nuget package or something then its equally got a 'Published' interface which is hard(er) to change.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think microservice architectures are better than libraries in "enforcing an interface contract," but they are better at *defining* contracts. Fowler is saying that code libraries generally have lots of public members, but only some of those are intended to form the published interface - the contract that is agreed upon between two or more components.

Presumably, this is because he thinks public members are very cheap to create, so discipline often fails us in limiting them.

Service endpoints (REST, messaging, etc) are much more explicit, and more expensive to create. They take more thought about compatibility, security and performance concerns. Because of this, you are likely to have fewer, but better defined, interfaces on your service, making it easier to decouple and re-implement services in the future.

Answer (score 2):

How are microservices better at enforcing an interface contract?

You cannot call into their internals. You can only call them through whatever interface they expose publicly.

With a library, a member or class not marked private can be called even if that was not intended. Or even if it was documented that users should not do so. When a user calls something meant to be "inside" your library, then that client code becomes tightly coupled with the library's internal implementation. Even when a library has private or internal members, many languages offer [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) capabilities that can allow you to (unwisely) access or invoke them.

With (micro)services, the isolation of internal parts is total. The only way to call them is through the public interface.

Answer (score 1):

> How are microservices better than libraries in enforcing an interface contract?

They aren't. In fact, arguably they are *worse*.

Both microservices and libraries have APIs. With libraries you normally can have compile/unit test guarantees of your interface contracts.

Microservices have (or should have...) the same interface contract. However, the ability to validate this is moved to either an integration test or worse, production environment verification.

This problem results in either:

1. cumbersome integration tests
2. lack of testing and hope that things *just work* in production environments

Note that this issue is one that contract testing is designed to solve. I encourage you to read through [Pact.io](https://docs.pact.io/) as they are more or less addressing the core problem here.